# INTERNAL ERROR: cannot create temporary directory

Tags: containers

I create the container useing golang reexec， golang executable binary can work, but python (pyinstaller -F ) executable binary not work.

python binary can work on host machine(ubuntu).

```
-[container]- # ls
123-file  functionA  functionA-mark  python-test  test  test22
-[container]- # ./python-test
[16] INTERNAL ERROR: cannot create temporary directory!
-[container]- # df -h
df: cannot read table of mounted file systems: No such file or directory
```

I expect the Python binary to run inside the container.

I`m beginner and  don't know where to set it in the container.

I sincerely hope to get your help， thanks